# BeautifulSoup: Unable to get text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the price of an item from eBay.com but for some reason I cannot.

```
price_BeautifulSoup = bs.find("span", {"id": "prcIsum"}).text
# What the console prints: "<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>"
```

What I have attempted:

- I have tried Googling `"class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'"`.
- `price_BeautifulSoup = bs.find('span', attrs={"id": "prcIsum"}).get_text().strip()`

[image]

Entire code: https://pastebin.com/Vb5gd7RL

Thanks in advance. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You printed the wrong variable:

```
print("price_BeautifulSoup", ": ", BeautifulSoup,"\n")
```

You wanted:

```
print("price_BeautifulSoup", ": ", price_BeautifulSoup ,"\n")
```

If you wanted an isolated price you could extract the content attribute

```
bs.select_one('#prcIsum')['content']
```

If you wanted to match selenium list output then split on space:

```
print("price_selenium", ": ", price_selenium)
print("price_BeautifulSoup", ": ", price_BeautifulSoup.split(' ') ,"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html = item.body
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
spans = parsed_html.find('span', attrs={"id": "prcIsum"})
body = spans.string
print(body)
```